# Localize app name

Tags: android, string, localization

I want to localize (values-ru) strings values: textview and app_name. App localizes only textview ("Привет мир") but app_name still the same ("Localization"). What's the problem with app_name localization?

App label name & activity label name in Manifest refer to the appropriate string value.

Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.local.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

String res/values-ru:

```
<resources>
<string name="hello_world">Привет мир</string>
<string name="app_name">Локализация</string>
</resources>
```

Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String languageToLoad  = "ru";
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will change the Locale of your application locally not the mobile. And Manifest pick the value of your application name as per the device locale, not application locale.
So you need to set it from settings of your mobile device.

Comment: this was a corrent answer. But i am sure it will help the community more if you tell how to set overcome the situation.

Answer (score 0):

@skygeek agree 
Just to enlighten the subject as per the android localization process from android website:

> Resources are text strings, layouts, sounds, graphics, and any other
>   static data that your Android application needs. An application can
>   include multiple sets of resources, each customized for a different
>   device configuration. When a user runs the application, Android
>   automatically selects and loads the resources that best match the
>   device's locale.

A detailed explanation can be found at android website [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).